# I am trying to generate a value count if true, if it falls within a date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I typed this formula but am getting an error... can anyone help?

```
=COUNTIFS(West!N6:N26,true,[West!C6:C26,>=1/1/21,date range,<=1/31/21])
```

Comment: This is for Excel

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SU. To get a better response, you should edit your post to include details of what error you're getting, preferably with a screenshot. Additionally, you should describe how you've tried to solve the problem yourself. From the text you pasted, you need to at least remove the `[` from formula and enclose the dates in double quotes. Additionally, the text "date range" won't work unless it's either replaced with a valid reference or defined as a named range that doesn't include a space.

Comment: You are looking for IF function: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function#:~:text=The%20IF%20function%20runs%20a%20logical%20test%20and,AND%20and%20OR%20to%20extend%20the%20logical%20test.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `IF()`:  in fact, `COUNTIFS()` is a wonderful substitute for `IF()` and far superior when you have a long list of conditions, even just five or six, as you can use Alt-Enter after each condition to stack them neatly in the formula editing bar which makes setting them up and maintaining them later hugely easier than the vile, nasty run-on sentence we call `IF()`.

As `FlexYourData` says, if you drop those inexplicable square brackets, and enclose the date portions in double quotes (like you see below), then so long as "date range" is made into a valid reference of some kind, you are in business:

```
=COUNTIFS(West!N6:N26,true,West!C6:C26,">=1/1/21",date range,"<=1/31/21")
```

First the date part. Your criteria cannot just be written like you have them. It was OK for the first criteria, `true`, because... well, because Excel is like that... But for the criteria that are not a logical TRUE/FALSE, you need to enclose the entire criteria in double quotes, or if it is an operator, such as ">=", and a function or formula, like `TODAY()` perhaps, then the operator has to be in double quotes while the function is not. So, not just the date itself, but the whole criteria, like above.

Now, "date range" cannot be a Named Range because NR's cannot have spaces in them. So one assumes you were going from a generalized, conceptual kind of formula to one with real ranges and such, like the West!C6:C26 one and just missed the third one leaving "date range"... in which case, putting something real in there, even a Named Range, will handle that difficulty. If I was mistaken and you really want "date range" there, well, you're never going to get it to work.

Final note:  about the double quotes around things. They are for Excel so it can tell you mean the literal value inside the double quotes. Excel compares the first part of the pair, the "criteria" to this value. So as above, the literal value inside the quote is used so Excel takes what it finds in the column N cell and adds your literal expression, so it adds the comparison operator AND the value after it so it has then built an expression that it can treat like a formula found in some cell and return TRUE or FALSE to itself and use that to decide to include or not include it in whichever xxxxxIF or xxxxxIFS function you are using's answer.

If you do NOT include the double quotes, Excel figures you entered a function (and when it cannot find that function in itself, it then looks to find it as a Named range and if it cannot, it returns an error for it which leads to a problem... (USUALLY... but not always! Talk about weird. However, the way it doesn't lead to a problem has no real use that can't be done better a different way. So use the double quotes if you are not using a function or a Named Range, and even when using a function, you have to quote the comparison operator (=, >, etc.). It can actually get a LOT more complicated sounding than that, but if you follow those ideas, and bear in mind that not using a comparison operator with a criteria tells Excel to use `=`, you can figure out most any of the situations you can encounter.

Your situation is simple though:  double quotes on the whole things, as you see above.